# Limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{ x} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, indeterminate-forms

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{ x} $$

What is wrong with this argument: as $x$ approaches zero, both $x$ and $(1-\cos x)$ approaches $0$.
**So the limit is $1$ .**

1. How can we prove that they approaches zero at same rate?
2. This is not about solving the limit because I already solved it but about the rate of both functions going to zero .

   m referring to $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{ x} =1 $$

Comment: What does this have to do with "infinite decimals"?

Comment: Changing the limit to 1 doesn't really help. The answer is indeed 0.

Comment: Yes I know , but my question is both what we taking the sine of and x goes to 0 . so by that rule , $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{ x} =1$$ it should be 1.

Comment: I see. I hope your doubt has been cleared now

Comment: Yes thank you all who took your time to help me :)

Comment: Do you actually mean "infinitesimals"?

Comment: Yes I do , what is wrong with that ? 
How close to Zero is close enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is wrong with this argument ; as $x$ approaches zero , both $x$ and $(1-\cos x)$ approaches $0$ .

The wrong thing is that both the numerator and denominator of your expression go to $0$ at the same time and then your limit assumes the form $\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined and inconclusive.

**RATE OF BOTH FUNCTIONS GOING TO ZERO**

You basically need to calculate the derivative of the $2$ functions to see which one goes to $0$ earlier.

Now $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin x\right)=\cos x$$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}\left( x \right)= 1$$

And we know that $\cos x \le 1$
So you know who goes to $0$ first.

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION**

However, better is to use proper formula for limits and solve it in this way:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{ x} $$
$$=\left[\lim_{(1-\cos x) \to 0} \frac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{(1-\cos x)}\right] \cdot  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos x)}{ x} $$
$$= 1\cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos x)}{ x}$$

And the limit has a simpler shape and has the form $\frac{0}{0}$.

So better to apply [L'Hospital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule//).

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos x)}{ x}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x)}{ 1 }$$
$$= 0$$

Hence you can say that the limit is $0$ by mathematical rigour.

Answer (score 1):

By your argument, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x}$$ is also $0$ because as $x$ approaches zero, both $x$ and $x$ approach $0$, so the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is flawed in the sense that if both the numerator and denominator tends to 0 nothing much can be told about the limit.
Remember $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeterminate. What matters is how fast each of them goes to 0.

In the question $1-\cos x= 2 \sin^2\frac{x}{2}$ goes to 0 much faster since for very small values of x $\sin x\sim x$, or $2 \sin^2\frac{x}{2} \sim 2(\frac{x}{2})^2=\frac{x^2}{2}$
Hence $\sin (1-\cos x)\sim \sin(\frac{x^2}{2}) \sim \frac{x^2}{2}$

Obviously $\frac{x^2}{2}$ goes to 0 much faster than $x$

Answer (score 0):

The question is not whether the numerator goes to $0$ (which is what you show), but whether it goes to $0$ *faster than the denominator*.

To see this (without L'Hopital) consider the following:

By the Taylor series, $1-\cos(x)=O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$.

Also, $\sin(x)=O(x)$, so $\sin(1-\cos(x))=O(x^2)$. This becomes a $O(x)$ when divided by the denominator $x$, so that the limit is $0$.

Comment: You say "without l'Hopital", and then you go straight to a Taylor series argument. You do know that they are the same thing, right?

Comment: I'm fully aware, but the OP may not be.. @Arthur

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with this argument ; as $x$ approaches zero , both $x$ and $(1-\cos x)$ approaches $0$ .
>   So the limit is 1.

What is wrong with this argument is that it is FALSE.

For example in $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac x{x^2}$ both $x$ and $x^2$ tend to zero, but the limit is $+\infty$.
As another example in $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {x^2}x$ both $x^2$ and $x$ tend to zero, but the limit is $0$.
And for $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {2x}x$ both $2x$ and $x$ tend to zero, but the limit is $2$.

So both numerator and denominator tending to zero **DO NOT** imply the fraction tends to $1$ or to any other pre-selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{ x} =1 .$$

This also implies that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{1-\cos x}
= \lim_{(1-\cos x) \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{1-\cos x} = 1 .$$

Therefore

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{x}
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{1-\cos x}
        \cdot \frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)\\
&=  \left( \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(1-\cos x)}{1-\cos x} \right)
 \cdot \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \right)\\
&=  1 \cdot \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \right),
\end{align}
provided that all those limits exist (which they do).

So the question now is, what is
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x}?$$

Hint: it is not $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If that can help you:

- in blue the plot of $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$,
- in green that of $\dfrac{\sin(1-\cos(x))}{x}$.

[image]

In fact, for small $x$, $\sin(x)\approx x$ and $\cos(x)\approx1-\dfrac{x^2}2$, so that the first function is approximately $1$ and the second $\dfrac x2$.